# No, my question is different, the dupe-voter misread it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I've received a dupe-vote on a question, and I'm getting

> This question may already have an answer here:
>
> That solved my problem!
>
> No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

How can I choose to say that I've already indicated how it's different, and the dupe-voter misread it?

Comment: Obviously, you click "I will edit" and then change the bit you already included to appear in bold caps inside of a quote block, preceded by a header reading "Please read more carefully you doofus close voter".

Comment: The irony, it burns...

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe since this one here is about the new OP-self-close mechanism, not duplicates in general.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe I should edit this question to make it more obvious. :)

Comment: lol, that would be a good idea! :D

Answer (score 14):

Without a question being linked to, it is hard to know what has happened in that particular question.

However, if another vote for a duplicate has arisen after you edited to try and distinguish them, then I think your only option is to choose "No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how." and to edit some more to try and make the distinction clearer.

I think the onus is on the asker to make their question clearly distinct from any near/proposed duplicates rather than expecting potential answerers to volunteer too much of their time to try and discern subtleties between similar questions.